# How to add today's date for the name of csv file using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, export-to-csv

Hello actually I have tried this code at the end of my query --> OUTPUT TO `'D:\\Report'+GETDATE ()+'.CSV'` but it doesn't work. Do you know where's the problem is? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that what kind of application you are having but this code worked for me. My application is based on PHP and I am extracting the data using SQL and then rendering the csv through application.

Hope this helps.

```
$filename = "Overall_ManPower_Report_".date('Y-m-d-g:ia').".csv";
header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename);
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $headerArray);
```

Comment: Please mark the answer correct if helped you or let me know if it is still not solved and I will try to update it.